# Got File Path But Also Need To Search Parent

Tags: php

I have the following string in my script.

```
$file_info = getTvShowInfoFromNfoFile(getPathOfNearbyFileWithExt($original_filepath, 'nfo'));
```

When I run the script it searchs the file path directory for the NFO file.

The NFO file is actually kept one level up.

Folder A
        file.nfo
        Folder A-1
                  File-Path.mov
        Folder A-2
                  File-Path.mov

Could anyone please help me and tell me what I need to add to the above string to make it search one level up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to go one level up from the specified filepath

```
$file_info = getTvShowInfoFromNfoFile(getPathOfNearbyFileWithExt("../".$original_filepath, 'nfo'));
```

Comment: Perfect.Thank You

Comment: @PaulTownsend glad to help